# Pipeline to publish obsidian to github and display that content in my '.com' domain?

Tags: dns, cname

These are the steps:

- I write my notes in obsidian, the note taking app.
- I Push them to github.
- Now it automatically converts itself to a website form in github, I might use obsidian garden or github for it. barnyard9.github.io/abcd
- Now whenever I want to access barnayard9.com, I need to see the contents of barnyard9.github.io/abcd